# Default input borders in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

By default, input elements are styled with `border: 2px inset`. However, as long as the background is white, the border displays as a thin gray line (with `#eee` color). But if I change the background even the slightest (e.g. `#feffff`), the border suddenly changes to what you would expect from `2px inset`. What is causing this weird behavior?

Here's an example (http://jsfiddle.net/ttb2fc1d/):

CSS

```
.border-test {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px inset;
    margin: 8px;
}
.gray {
    background-color: #feffff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="border-test"></div>
<input class="border-test"></input>
<input class="border-test gray"></input>
```

This results in the first and third boxes having inset borders, while the second one has a thin-line border:

[image: Borders]

Comment: that is weird man. changing bg colors affects border styles?

Comment: it seems browser specific (I can only see it in Chrome), which makes sense because it has to do with default styling

Comment: ^ I realize the above statement is dumb because the title has the words ".. in Chrome"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the input element on Chrome inherits from its stylesheet

```
 -webkit-appearance:textfield;
```

And textfield has just 1px light-grey borders.

Try to add the following and you will see that also the input will have the same border inset even if white:

```
.border-test {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px inset;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/zqmbvn7v/1/

Comment: Nice info! I wish we had standard input styling across browsers

Comment: I am in awe of your css zen

Comment: Css nowadays has become so powerful and full of features that web-development is trickier than ever :)

Comment: Okay, but why does changing the background color disable the appearance?

Comment: For some reason whenever you change the background colour it also changes its state to a non textfield. Apparently textfield is meant to accept only white as background color to keep its UI state. If you set any other input with a different background color you will still see the same 2px borders applied and not the textfield appearance.

Comment: Look [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/). It appears that `appearance` is there to fill a hole if a `input` doesn't have default styling.

Comment: Maybe when you define a `background` style it removes the `appearance` style defined by Chrome, which also contains a `border` style? I dunno

Comment: If I explicitly define `background-color:#fff`, it will still keep its appearance, though.