# Get browsers default form control border color

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit, border

I am creating a custom form control and would like to set border colour to default browser form element border colour.

Anyone knows if this is possible and how? By looking at generated code I can see something like this:

```
border-color: initial;
```

This is color in google for INPUT:

[image]

And this is what I get if I use `initial`:
[image]

Obviously two colors are significantly different.
Similarly I would like to know default border-width and style.

**Update**

Just to be more clear, my component is a `div` that wraps multiple controls. I don't want to enforce my style, I want to allow user to use default browser style if they wish.

Comment: Won't this be different for all browsers? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572547/default-input-borders-in-chrome

Comment: It would, unless user sets some specific style. The idea is not to influence style, but rather leave it to browser or user to decide how it would look.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need:

> border-color: unset;
>   border-width: unset;
>   border-style: unset;

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It removes border completely. Just to clarify, my component is DIV acting as a form control.

Comment: That's because default border-style is no style at all. Take a look at this fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6fpgoxq/ . 'form-wrapper' class sets border settings to '2px dotted red', try removing comments from properties of the 'form-wrapper-default' class, it sets up every property to browser's default. Don't forget to click 'Run' to try every variant.